# How can I get data from RSS by date in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am working on a small script where I wanna take only my website's latest post which is posted yesterday mean I wanna get all yesterday's links and titles.
I tried with my script but I am getting all URLs I am not sure how can I fix it.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

I was wondering if I can use 'where' attribute like we usually use in SQL. I want only 1 days posts to be scraped.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$url = "https://www.lifegoals.co.in/feed/";
$i=0;
 $invalidurl = false;
 if(@simplexml_load_file($url)){
  $feeds = simplexml_load_file($url);
 }else{
  $invalidurl = true;
  echo "<h2>Invalid RSS feed URL.</h2>";
 }
 if(!empty($feeds)){

  //$site = $feeds->channel->title;
  //$sitelink = $feeds->channel->link;

  //echo "<h1>".$site."</h1>";
  foreach ($feeds->channel->item as $item) {

   $title = $item->title;
   $link = $item->link;
   //$description = $item->description;
   $postDate = $item->pubDate;
   $pubDate = date('D, d M Y',strtotime($postDate));
   $currDate = date('D, d M Y');
   if($i>=10) break;   
   if($pubDate=$currDate){
   $rss =   "<item>
                <title>$title</title>
                <link>$link</link>
            </item>";     
            
   echo $rss;   
   $i++;
   }
  } 
  }
?>
```

**i want only 1 days posts there are 4 days posts**

Comment: Be aware that here `if($pubDate=$currDate){` it should be `==`

Comment: Yaa Thanks what a small mistake i did.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Now how can I close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if($pubDate==$currDate){
   $rss =   "<item>
                <title>$title</title>
                <link>$link</link>
            </item>";     
            
   echo $rss;   
   $i++;
   }
```

The `==` was missing thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add some debugging to this to ensure that you're getting what you think you want. Try the following in your foreach loop:

```
    print_r([
        $postDate,
        $pubDate,
        $currDate,
        ($pubDate == $currDate),
    ]);
```